# round behaviour differs between python2 and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rounding

HELP
Im currently using a book, but it seems like its wrong or something.
This is what I enter:

```
round(10)
10
>>> round(10.0)
10
>>> round(10.2)
10
>>> round(8.7)
9
>>> round(4.5, 1)
4.5
>>> round(4.5, 2)
4.5
>>> round(4.5, 3)
4.5
>>> round (4.5)
4
>>> round(4.5)
4
```

Here is what the book says should happen:

```
round(10)
10
>>> round(10.0)
10.0
>>> round(10.2)
10.0
>>> round(8.7)
9.0
>>> round (4.5)
5
```

Comment: You are probably using Python 3, and the book is for Python 2.

Comment: Forget the book. Look at what round is supposed to do...You can get the behavior described by the book by supplying the number of significant digits. `round(10.0, 1)` --> 10.0. The docs say "digits (default 0 digits)." __NOTE__: This is for Python 2.7x

Comment: @LOL, LOL......

Comment: Was the book for python 2 or python 3?  Were you using python 2 or 3?  My guess - the book was written for python 2 and you are using python 3.

Comment: Actually, we are both using the same version of python...

Comment: @LOL Are you *sure*? What does the book say it is using? What happens when you use `>>> import sys; sys.version` in your shell?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nothing.... its still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python2.7

```
>>> round(10.0)
10.0
>>> round(10.0, 0)
10.0
```

Python3.4, 3.5, and 3.6

```
>>> round(10.0)
10
>>> round(10.0, 0)
10.0
>>>
```

Two takeaways:

1. `round` in python3 returns an `int` (when it can) while in python2 returns `float` (always).
2. Read a book for python3!

Comment: For me round(10.0) is returning 10. Using Python3.6.1

Comment: Ok...im using 3.5.1, is that it?

Comment: @LOL Can confirm, 3.5 shows the same behaviour. Now you can safely assume you're reading the wrong book. Cheers.